# Метод поиска в тексте слов, введенных в другой строке

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Пока работал с консолью, без проблем описывал метод поиска через циклы и вектор символов `char`.  
Когда перешел к формам, столкнулся с проблемой. Я не понимаю, как работать с типом данных `System::String^`, который необходим для работы с `TextBox` и `RichTextBox`. 
 Пытался сделать преобразование в char и посмотреть, что в итоге у меня выведет, примерно таким образом:

```
System::String^ str;  
str=TextBox->Text;  
char ch = str[2];  
TextBox->Text=System::Convert::ToString(ch);
```

В итоге, у меня char конвертировался как целочисленное значение, а не как символ и на экран выводит ASCII код символа, вместо самого символа.
После замены `char` на `System::Char^` все заработало нормально.
Так вот вопрос, что это за типы данных, чем они отличаются от стандартных `string` и `char` и каким образом их передавать в пользовательский класс обработки?
Пока у меня была только одна мысль. Создать массив элементов типа `int`, куда циклом загрузить `ASCII` коды символов из `System::String^`, после чего передать этот массив в метод пользовательского класса, где и проводить обработку.
Но неужели такие сложности в элементарной задаче "Подготовить к обработке вводимый пользователем массива символов".  Для того что бы ввести число-обработать-вывести, его нужно как минимум 2 раза конвертировать.

Win Form Application C++ VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут написано про [System::String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.aspx)

```
char - ANSI, System::Char - Юникод;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я тут нагуглить успел.  
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli/thread251312.html  
Ссылка очень помогла, может кому пригодится.